# Using command to start application

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, xamarin.forms, cortana

Question is simple but answer is not present anywhere!
Is there possibility to use Cortana to start my app with Command "Hey MyApp" instead of "Hey Cortana"?

I don’t mean to run Cortana then say run my app via voice command.
Than you for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible. "Hey Cortana" is the only thing that triggers the voice recognition, this is built into the Windows core.

If they would not have done that it would cause a lot of processing power to constantly having to listen and evaluate what one is saying. And on the other hand you could easily trigger all kind of actions and apps by just having your phone next to you and talking to another person.

Therefore, the start point for any voice command will be "Hey Cortana" on Windows, "Ok Google" on Android and "Hey Siri" on iOS.

You can implement certain '[skills](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/getstarted)' into Cortana, with which you can trigger actions within your app.

To get started, head over to the [Cortana Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana).

Comment: Thank you for answer, one follow up question is - can I achieve it via my custom backgroud process?